Existence of a sequence of $-1/1$-polytopes with certain geometric properties
Let $P_n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a sequence of polytopes (A polytope is the convex hull of finitely many points). Let $B_n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ denote the Euclidean unit ball. I am interested in sequences of polytopes with a rather strange list of properties:

There exists some fixed $r>0$ such that for all $n$, we have $rB_n \subset P_n $
$\log N_n = o(n)$, where $N_n := N(P_n , B_n)$ denote the covering number of $P_n$ by $B_n$, that is, the least number of translates of $B_n$ needed to cover $P_n$.

I don't know of a lot fundamentally different classes of examples of such sequences, but I do know a few. A conjecture of Milman and Szarek states that 1 + 2 implies that the set of vertices $V_{n}$ of $P_n$ has (at least) exponential size.
I would like to add $\textbf{condition 3}$: I further demand that the set $V_n$ is a subset of the vertex set of the unit cube, that is, that for all $n$ and for all $v \in V_n$ we have that $v_i \in \{\pm 1 \}$ for all indices $i$.
The question is: Does a sequence satisfying conditions 1+2+3 exist? (And the bigger $r$ can be made, the better!)

Can you please give an example where 1+2 is true?

The most trivial example, for $r=\frac{1}{2}$, say, is any sequence of polytoped such that $\frac{1}{2} B_n \subset P_n \subset B_n $. Such a sequence can easily be constructed by choosing the vertices of $P_n$ to be any $\varepsilon$-net for the sphere $S^{n-1}$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$.

That makes sense, thanks!
